# Cannot Ctrl+V in TextField with OpenFL Legacy Cpp Build

Tags: haxe, openfl, haxeui

I am currently working on an application using the HaxeUI library. In my application, I am creating `TextInput` objects, which are based off of OpenFL's `TextField`. Unfortunately, when compiling for Windows or Neko, these fields do not allow for basic faculties like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>, or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd>.

As a result, I felt that I could just make my own extension of the `TextInput` class which simply uses the `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` event to detect these particular functions. The below is a relevant snippet of my implementation:

```
class SmartTextInput extends TextInput {
    public function new() {
        super();
        this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, performPress);
    }

    private function performPress(e:KeyboardEvent):Void {
        if(e.ctrlKey) {
            trace("CTRL PRESSED!");
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case Keyboard.V: trace("PASTE!");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like if I press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and then <kbd>V</kbd>, it should print out `"CTRL PRESSED!"` and `"PASTE!"`. However, I only ever get `"CTRL PRESSED!"`, so it doesn't work. In fact, after some vigorous testing, I found that if the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> button is being held, then `KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN` will not register any other keypress except the <kbd>Alt</kbd> and <kbd>Shift</kbd> keys. In other words, detecting <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> and <kbd>V</kbd> being held simultaneously is impossible *unless* <kbd>V</kbd> is pressed first; however, since conventionally <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> is pressed first, this doesn't work for me.

Is there a way I can register actions like <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> in a `TextField` in OpenFL for Windows? Or at least, is there a way I can detect the sequential key presses of <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>, followed by <kbd>V</kbd>? I've tried having <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> on `KEY_DOWN` and <kbd>V</kbd> on `KEY_UP`, but it is not responsive enough for practical use.

I am using OpenFL 3.6.0, Lime 2.9.0, and HaxeUI 1.8.17.  It should be noted that HaxeUI requires OpenFL Legacy. In non-legacy OpenFL, I was able to get <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> working just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is why they made OpenFL next. I'm not sure if it's not possible or not easy to detect those keypresses in legacy, but I highly doubt that functionality would be added at this point since you got it to work with next.

So it's kind of a *"Will OpenFL add to their legacy codebase?"* versus *"When does the next major version of HaxeUI come out?"* There are enough issues with TextFields on next that they're probably not going to also fix legacy's longstanding problems. And a new HaxeUI is coming eventually.

So... no you can't. Not yet.

Answer (score 0):

After some thinking about it, I came to realize the lack of responsiveness when using KEY_UP as a workaround was the result of releasing CTRL before V.  In normal applications, this is possible because the paste action happens upon key down.

To get around this, I simply applied a delay on the release of CTRL:

```
class SmartTextInput extends TextInput {
    public function new() {
        super();
        ctrlDown = false;
        this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN, keyDown);
        this.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP, keyUp);
    }

    private static inline var CTRL_SENSITIVITY = 100;
    private var ctrlDown:Bool;

    private function keyDown(e:KeyboardEvent):Void {
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.CONTROL || e.keyCode == Keyboard.COMMAND)
            ctrlDown = true;
    }

    private function keyUp(e:KeyboardEvent):Void {
        if (e.keyCode == Keyboard.CONTROL || e.keyCode == Keyboard.COMMAND)
        //  The delay here is for people who release control before releasing the letter key
            Timer.delay(function() {  ctrlDown = false; }, CTRL_SENSITIVITY);
        if (ctrlDown) {
            switch(e.keyCode) {
                case Keyboard.C: copy();
                case Keyboard.V: paste();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Though not optimal, this is seems to work well enough.

Comment: That's so gross haha